# Node/Knex/Heroku: node-config not pulling / evaluating references to environment vars

Tags: node.js, heroku, config, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have the following in my node-config .json file, referencing an environment variable `DATABASE_URL`.  However, my config reads this just as the actual string `DATABASE_URL` and does not evaluate it, pull from the environment var.

How do I get this to read the environment variable?  Thanks

**Config**
staging.json | production.json

```
"knex": {
  "client": "postgresql",
  "connection": "DATABASE_URL", // ** What is the best way to get this to eval?
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Knex configuration is usually in JavaScript file `knexfile.js` and not in JSON.

In JavaScript file you can simply check env variable from `process.env.DATABASE_URL`.

In JSON file there is no way to read values from environment variables.